# The genus of a certain kind of cubic

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

I have a cubic curve that looks like

$$ a_0 x^3 + a_1 x^2 y + a_2 xy^2 + a_3 y^3 = b $$

with $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$, and $b$ all integers, and $a_0$ and $b$ nonzero.  I'm not sure but I think in my situation $a_3$ is nonzero as well.

I'd like to know whether this curve has infinitely-many integer points.  As I understand it, [Siegel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points) implies that the curve has only finitely-many integer points, so long as its genus is positive.  However, algebraic geometry is pretty far from my normal area, and I have no idea how to determine the genus of such a curve.  Hence,

**Question**: Does such a curve necessarily have positive genus?  If not, is there an easily-described counterexample?  Or, is there a proof that such a curve has only finitely-many integer solutions that does not go through Siegel's theorem?

Answer (score 2):

A cubic curve is either *rational* (`genus $0$`) if it has a double point or a cusp, or *elliptic* (`genus 1`) if it is a smooth curve.

If a cubic is elliptic, its points can be given the structure of an abelian group, and *Mordell-Weil's theorem* states that the curve on $\mathbf Q$  is a finitely generated abelian group. To make the structure of group effective, you must use *Weierstraß normal form*.

Siegel's theorem says an elliptic cubic has a finite number of points with first coordinates in the ring of integers of an algebraic number field.

Comment: Are you saying that for the curve to have positive genus it must be of the form $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, with $a$ and $b$ rational?  Or is "genus $1$" the definition of "elliptic"?

Comment: Formally, an elliptic curve over a field$K$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $1$ + a specified point. It can be shown it is isomorphic to a cubic curve with an affine equation of the form: $$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6, \quad a_i\in K.$$

Comment: So, if $a_3$ is nonzero in my question, then the curve is not elliptic and hence has genus $0$?

Comment: Not necessarily, because the form  for the equation must be obtained after a change of coordinates. The only way to test it, is to look for a singularity..

Comment: And a singularity is a double point or cusp?

Comment: As far as I remember, for a cubic curve, yes.